# Reference request: fusion rules for unitary dual of SL(3,R)?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis

By the fusion rules, I mean: given two unitary irreps of the group, what unitary irreps occur in their tensor product and with what "multiplicity"? (I am guessing that direct integrals rather than direct sums will be needed.)

Some searching online turned up a short note by Neretin (Ukrainian Math Journal 1998) which gives an outline that looks quite accessible. However, the MathReview of that paper points out that Neretin quotes a statement by Kirillov that had a gap in its original proof, although apparently the desired claim (restricting an irrep to the parahoric subgroup) is true in the case which Neretin requires.

Anyway: while it seems I could get by with Neretin's outline and doing some work to check and decompress, I wondered if there was some other source, perhaps in a book, which explicitly stated these fusion rules.

Comment: Do you care about all irreducible representations, or just the tempered ones?

Comment: Good point. I think that for now, I'd be interested just to have a reference for the tempered unitary irreps.